# Email address Policy is invalid

Tags: exchange, powershell

I have setup an accepted domain, everything in the background is done, I am in the process of setting up the mail policy using the following command:

`New-EmailAddressPolicy -Name “x.com” -IncludedRecipients “MailboxUsers” -ConditionalCompany “xx” -Priority “Lowest” -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates “SMTP:%g.%s@x.com ”`

I get the following error

```
New-EmailAddressPolicy : Cannot convert SMTP:%g.%s@x.com to the type Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ProxyAddressTemplateCollection required by parameter 'EnabledEmailAddressTemplates'. Cannot perform this operation with the address 'SMTP:%g.%s@xz.com because it is invalid: The SMTP e-mail address template "%g.%s@xz.com " is invalid.At line:1 char:174+ New-EmailAddressPolicy-Name "xz.com" -IncludedRecipients "MailboxUsers" -ConditionalCompany "xz" -Priority "Lowest" -EnabledEmailAddressTemplates <<<<  "SMTP:%g.%s@xz.com "+ CategoryInfo: InvalidArgument: (:) [New-EmailAddressPolicy], ParameterBindingException+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.Exchange.Managem  ent.SystemConfigurationTasks.NewEmailAddressPolicy
```

I have setup the new accepted domain as an authoritative domain type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a space at the end of your string: `“SMTP:%g.%s@x.com "`. When you change that to `"SMTP:%g.%s@x.com"` it should work.